# why input Chinese word do not to judge in python?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

a = '中文'
b = raw_input()

if a == b:
    print 'ok'
else:
    print 'no'

#After execute，input‘中文’,but print 'no'.
```

Comment: Possibly terminal encoding is not utf-8 so the byte strings don't compare equal. Hard to say without more info.

Comment: Thank you answer my question.I try a.strip() == b.strip(), but it still print 'no'.